# How to get the value button in JAVA springboot

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How to access and print out the `table-row` value in console when it's clicked?

My HTML Code

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="taskJob : ${theTaskSchJobList}" style="text-align: center">
    <td th:text="${taskJob.id}">Id</td>
    <td th:text="${taskJob.title}">Username</td>
    <td th:text="${taskJob.script}">Script</td>
    <td>
        <form th:action="@{RunJob}" method="POST"
              class="form-horizontal" id="RunScriptJob">
            <!--START Button-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" th:object="${taskJob.script}"
                    th:value="${taskJob.script}" th:name="${taskJob.script}"
                    th:id="${taskJob.script}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
            </button>

            <!--RESET Button-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
            </button>
        </form>

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

My Controller- its return to null,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/RunJob", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String theJob(HttpServletRequest req) {

    String script = req.getParameter("taskJob.script");

    System.out.println("#######>>>>>" + script);

    return "redirect:/cronJob";

}
```

my diagram table [diagram table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKaoq.png)

Comment: you need to register a callback function on button click.

Comment: Set the button name to something known, eg `name="taskJobScript"`. Then you can simply add a `@RequestParam String taskJobScript` argument to your `theJob` method

Comment: @MehrajMalik _Java_, not _JavaScript_